# Dismiss UIPickerView dynamically via script or via Storyboard

Tags: ios, uipickerview, storyboard, picker, dismiss

I'm facing many problems in implementing UIPickerView on iOS.
I would like to show a Picker to populate a certain field, but only when the field is selected, and dismiss (or hide) the Picker in other cases. Possibly with an animation.

- **STORYBOARD:**

I was able to reference it with an outlet, populate and show it on my ViewController. But I wasn't able to dynamically dismiss (or hide) the UIPickerView with Storyboard. 
I've tried with:

```
pickerView.hidden = YES;
```

but it didn't work. Any ideas?

---

- **CODING**

I tried to implement my Picker programmatically:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
//if click on fieldWithPicker, dismiss the keyaboard and load the picker
if (textField == fieldWithPicker)
{        
    //dismiss the keyboard of fieldWithoutPicker
    [fieldWithoutPicker resignFirstResponder];
    // Check if the picker is already on screen. If so, skip creating picker view and go to handling choice
    if (myPickerView.superview == nil)
    {           
        //Make picker
        myPickerView = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
        CGSize pickerSize = [myPickerView sizeThatFits:CGSizeZero];
        myPickerView.frame = [self pickerFrameWithSize:pickerSize];
        myPickerView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
        myPickerView.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;
        // this view controller is the data source and delegate
        myPickerView.delegate = self;
        myPickerView.dataSource = self;

        // Add the picker
        [self.view.window addSubview: myPickerView];

        // size up the picker view to our screen and compute the start/end frame origin for our slide up animation
        // compute the start frame
        CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame];
        CGRect startRect = CGRectMake(0.0, screenRect.origin.y + screenRect.size.height, pickerSize.width, pickerSize.height);
        mypickerView.frame = startRect;
        // compute the end frame
        CGRect pickerRect = CGRectMake(0.0, screenRect.origin.y + screenRect.size.height - pickerSize.height-100, pickerSize.width, pickerSize.height);

        // start the slide up animation
        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:PICKER_ANIMATION_DURATION];
        // Give time for the table to scroll before animating the picker's appearance
        [UIView setAnimationDelay:PICKER_ANIMATION_DELAY];

        // we need to perform some post operations after the animation is complete
        [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
        myPickerView = pickerRect;
        [UIView commitAnimations];
    }
    //we don't want keyboard, since we have a picker
    return NO;
}

//if click on fieldWithoutPicker, dismiss the picker and load the keyboard
if (textField == fieldWithoutPicker)
{
    [self hidePickerContinenteView];
}
return YES;
}
```

Then I've implemented my `hidePickerContinenteView` function to move outside the Picker:

```
- (void) hidePickerContinenteView
{
CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame];
CGRect endFrame = self.view.frame;
endFrame.origin.y = screenRect.origin.y + screenRect.size.height;

// start the slide down animation
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:PICKER_ANIMATION_DURATION];

// we need to perform some post operations after the animation is complete
[UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
[UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(slideDownDidStop)];

pickerContinenteView.frame = endFrame;
[UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

At this point I've two main problems:

- In the `textFieldShouldBeginEditing` method, I check it the PickerView already exists and in case, nothing is done. In the `hidePickerContinenteView` method I hide the Picker, but the PickerView continues to exist: this means that the next time I click on fieldWithPicker, the Picker is not displayed.
  I've tried using in the `hidePickerContinenteView` method the following:
  `[pickerContinenteView removeFromSuperview];`
  but this dismiss immediately the PickerView and according to this, no animation is displayed.
  Any ideas?
- If the Picker is displayed and the user changes the view, for example clicking on another tab or on the back button, the Picker is not dismissed. Any ideas also on this?

Thank you in advance,
yassa

Answer (score 0):

I would approach this by creating and placing the picker in storyboard where you want it to be when it is visible and used. Check the hidden box in the attribute inspector so it will be hidden when the view loads. Make sure it is on top of any other view you have in storyboard. Then code your view controller to use the hidden property to show it and again to hide. You can still use animation for changing the hidden property.

To hide the picker use:

```
[templatePicker setHidden:YES];
```

and to show the picker use:

```
[templatePicker setHidden:NO];
```

Comment: Concerning the first question, this worked like a charm, thank you!!!
But if the user changes view by clicking on another tab for example, the Picker remains visible. How can I intercept this event? Note that `textFieldShouldEndEditing` event doesn't' fire since on `textFieldShouldStartEditing` I must return NO to avoid the keyboard to appear.

Comment: I can't figure out that behavior. If you only create the picker using storyboard it should go away when you segue from the view containing the picker to another view.

Comment: And is it possible to display an animation on this picker? I mean: I put my picker not visible on the storyboard. Then for a certain event, I set it visible in a certain position and then I move it to another position...